# How to compare two .wav files in C#

Tags: c#, wav

I am playing a .wav file stored in my computer and I am going to record the speech of an user into a .wav file. For recording i'm using this link.

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/GemingLeader/696/

Now I want to compare these two .wav files. Can any one help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by `compare`? Byte for byte to see if it's the same size? Similar audio content after performing a FFT?

Comment: Question is unclear. They are two distinct files, so what kind of 'compare' do you want to do?

Comment: I want to check whether the user has said the exact thing which he heard when I'm playing the first audio file

Answer (score 2):

look at the SpeechSDK5.1 http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyId=5E86EC97-40A7-453F-B0EE-6583171B4530&displaylang=en

If you look at the following: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/SoundCatcher.aspx you can notice the Spectrogram, basically if the two spectrograms are exact same thing, then the audio is exact same thing. You need to capture the spectrogram data and use some sort of comparing algorithm to compare both data.

Comment: Do you have any links or references to options on how to capture appropriate spectrogram data?   This will be helpful for future readers and I am interested in how to do this.